# what is the meaning of arr[i]:0:14 in Pascal?

Tags: c, pascal

Can anyone please tell me. I'm trying to understand a Pascal code in which there is one line `writeln(arr[i]:0:14);`

Can anyone please tell me the meaning of this in C ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a format for real numbers:

```
writeln( foo:N:M );
```

prints the value of `foo` in a field width of `N` and shows `M` decimal places. So in `C` you'd use:

```
printf( "%N.Mf\n", foo );
```

If `N` is is too small to hold the formatted value (given the size of `M`), it will use the space it needs to print the number.

In Pascal, you may have `N` and/or `M` be variables. In that case, in `C`, you could create the format string as follows:

```
char my_fmt[50];  // could pick a "smarter" length for the string; this is just for example

sprintf( my_fmt, "%%%d.%df\n", N, M );
printf( my_fmt, foo );
```

Or even simpler:

```
printf( "%*.*f\n", N, M, foo );
```

Comment: In Pascal, n and m could be variables. So while it might be the same for the simple case in the example, it might be necessary to construct the formatting string.

Comment: You don't need `sprintf()` to generate the format string: `printf("%*.*f\n", N, M, foo);` is so much simpler, don't you think?

Comment: @ElchononEdelson yes that is simpler and I had that in the back of my mind. It's been so long since I've needed or used it, I wasn't sure about it. I've added it to the answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

It will print arr[i] with right justification to a minimal total width of 0, with 14 digits of precision after the decimal separator (a point in the old skool pascal case).

Note that a total width of 0 essentially disables the justification, but it must be there to be able to specify a decimal separator precision.

The double formatting arguments means that arr[i] must be a float type. (or fixed point currency type, in Delphi)

Be careful when translating array indices from Pascal to C. Pascal arrays might have a non zero lower bound, and then you will have to translate the array indice accordingly.

```
var xx : array [m..n] of double
```

becomes

```
double xx[n-m+1];
```

with all array indices corrected by subtracting m.  like

```
arr[x-m])
```